# SQL date interval comparison

Tags: sql, date, intervals

i have a report which i'm doing for work which i need some help with. The below query i shows what i've done so far, what i need now is to be able to get the info for each student that dropped on a day to day basis rather than give me a total at once, in other words take start one for example which is between 04-23 and 05-23 rather than getting the total at once i want it to provide results for each day at the time meaning today the results will show from 04-23 to 04-26 and tomorrow it updates to show results from 04-23 to 04-27 and so on and so forth. I would greatly appreciate if someone could please help. Thanks wise ones

```
SELECT
      COUNT (dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.priorqecounter) AS 'Prior to QE',
      COUNT (dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.duringqecounter) AS 'During QE',
      COUNT (dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.afterqecounter) AS 'After QE',
      dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.Division,
      dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.Campus,
      LEFT(CONVERT (VARCHAR,dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.Startdate  , 101), 10)AS 'Start Date'


FROM dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw
      --JOIN dbo.cst_AdStatusChanges_vw
            --ON dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.NewStatDescrip = dbo.cst_AdStatusChanges_vw.NewStatDescrip
WHERE StartDate IN ('2012-04-23', '2012-05-07', '2012-03-12')


GROUP BY dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.division, dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.campus, dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.startdate
ORDER BY dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.division, dbo.cst_AdCancelsQE_vw.campus ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `WHERE` today-yesterday-and the day before, you should say Between TODAY and TODAY - 3 days.

```
WHERE StartDate Between getdate() and getdate()-3
```

There you have an example for the last 3 days. You should be able to make it fix your requirements.
This way you have a query that works on a daily basis, if you run it today you get results for last 3 days, when it's tomorrow and you run it again, you'll get a new set of results.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, one question though if i use getdate when the start date is 04-23-2012 which clearly isn't today's date, isn't that not going to work?

Comment: no, `getdate()` would only work for today. If you want to consider an interval not working with `getdate()` you have a few options. 1: do `getdate()-X`, being X the quantity of days needed. e.g. if you need that date to be a week ago, you do `between getdate()-7 and getdate()-10`. 2nd option. You set a variable outside WHERE condition. And then you do `Between MyVariable and MyVariable - 3`. Hope this helps.